# I want to loop through information on a webpage html. Im not an expert in html but I know what I want from the code

Tags: html, vba

```
     </div>
  <p id="content-profile-view">  
     <h3 class="content-profile-title" id="content-profile-title-profile">
     Member Profile  </h3>
     <div class="content-profile-display" id="content-profile-display-profile">
       <fieldset class="fieldgroup group-membership"><legend>Membership</legend><div class="field field-type-text field-field-membertype">
        <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item odd">
                  <div class="field-label-inline-first">
          Member Type:&nbsp;</div>
                          Fellow        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

In the HTML above I want to return Member Type: Fellow. My code below will get me Member Type: BUT I can't seem to get the Fellow  Part. See my code below in vba.

```
 Dim collection As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim element As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement, subElement As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
 
 Dim a As String
 Dim b As String
 
  Set collection = Doc.getElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each element In collection
        If element.className = "field-label-inline-first" Then
           a = element.innerText
           Debug.Print a            
           
        End If
    Next element
```

Comment: the html appears to be malformed(or truncated).  can you post more of the surrounding code(specifically the code above the first div tag)?

Comment: I tried to add more of the html in there. Im not a html expert. Its a pretty massive piece so I only want to put in a truncated piece of the code that hopefully illustrates what Im looking for.

Comment: More html can be seen now. Any help folks??

Answer (score 1):

to get the second piece of data, you'll need to look for divs with the class 'field-item', because fellow is included in that overall div, not the filed-label-inline-first div

I've reformatted the content below to make it more obvious what is going on here.

```
<div class="field-item odd">
   <div class="field-label-inline-first">Member Type:&nbsp;</div>
   Fellow        
</div>
```